# How to assign session IDs to log data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use pandas to assign a session ID to the following log data, but I don't know how to do it.

```
user time 
0    2020-05-23 00:01:19
0    2020-05-23 00:13:32
1    2020-05-23 00:13:45
0    2020-05-23 12:59:45
2    2020-05-23 13:13:13
1    2020-05-23 15:13:45
```

`user` is a unique ID to identify the user, and `time` is the time the user accessed the site.
If the same user accessed the site within 6 hours, the same session ID will be assigned.
If the user is different, the session ID will be different.

Therefore, the above example can be complemented as follows.

```
user time                 session_id
0    2020-05-23 00:01:19  0
0    2020-05-23 00:13:32  0
1    2020-05-23 00:13:45  1
0    2020-05-23 12:59:45  2
2    2020-05-23 13:13:13  3
1    2020-05-23 15:13:45  4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
#ensure that time column is of dtype datetime
```

try via `pd.Grouper()` and `groupby()`:

```
df['session_id']=df.groupby(['user',pd.Grouper(key='time',freq='6H')],sort=False).ngroup()
```

output of `df`:

```
user    time                session_id
0   0   2020-05-23 00:01:19     0
1   0   2020-05-23 00:13:32     0
2   1   2020-05-23 00:13:45     1
3   0   2020-05-23 12:59:45     2
4   2   2020-05-23 13:13:13     3
5   1   2020-05-23 15:13:45     4
```